# Use minisat to find all solutions to SAT

Tags: shell-script

I am solving SAT instances using minisat. The syntax is `minisat inputfile outputfile`. However, it only returns one solution. To find all solutions I have to append the negation of the first solution to the original instance and solve again until it is unsolvable. The output file looks like this:

```
SAT
1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 -7 0
```

So each natural number from one to whatever is either negated or unnegated followed by a 0. I need to multiply each number by -1 and append that (last) line  (including the 0) to the end of `inputfile` and loop it until the first line of `outputfile` is `UNSAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications to Wumpus Q. Wumbley's script to make it useful. Most importantly, I added a counter to display the number of solutions and silenced the verbose MINISAT output as well as adding some important pipes to temporary files to preserve the input files. Lastly, it removes the requirement to provide an output files so you can call it SCRIPTNAME FILENAME from the command line.

```
#!/bin/sh
SOLUTIONS=0
cp $1 /tmp/tmpsat
while :; do

  minisat -verb=0 /tmp/tmpsat /tmp/tmpout > /tmp/tmpmsg 2> /tmp/tmpmsg

  if [ `head -1 /tmp/tmpout` = UNSAT ]; then
    break
  fi
 SOLUTIONS=$((SOLUTIONS + 1))
  tail -1 /tmp/tmpout |
    awk '{
      for(i=1;i<NF;++i) { $i = -$i }
      print
    }' >> /tmp/tmpsat

done

echo There are $SOLUTIONS solutions.
rm -f /tmp/tmpsat
rm -f /tmp/tmpout
rm -f /tmp/tmpmsg
```

Answer (score 2):

This script does what you ask:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :; do
  minisat inputfile outputfile
  if [ `head -1 outputfile` = UNSAT ]; then
    break
  fi
  tail -1 outputfile |
    awk '{
      for(i=1;i<NF;++i) { $i = -$i }
      print
    }' >> inputfile
done
```

The awk does the work of negating the row of numbers by setting `$i = -$i` for each `i` from 1 to `NF` (Number of Fields).